# Get data from clipboard on paste with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, copy-paste

What kind of JS would be needed to implement functionality similar to [this](http://snag.gy/) site? I only need it to get text from the clipboard when the user presses ctrl V, no fancy fetching data from raw filepaths or anything. Any libraries that do this? I just need a starting point, I couldn't find much by searching. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need javascript, you need flash. Seriously!

Comment: It seems like that specific site is using Java applets, wich would be another option.

Comment: https://github.com/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know javascript does not directly support this functionality as it appears as a possible security issue. However you should be able to do this using Flash: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html